# Why aren't my functions working as expected in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am trying to figure out why MYSQL isn't working as expected.

I imported my data from a CSV into a table called Products, which is shown in the screenshot. It's a small table of just ID and Name.

[image]

But when I run the where clause, finding out where the Name = 'SMS', it returns nothing? I don't understand what the issue is.

My CSV contents in Notepad++ is shown below:

[image]

This is what I used to load in my CSV, if there are any errors here.

[image]

Comment: You do not get any error messages?

Comment: No, it just says 0 rows returned

Comment: Ensure there's no trailing white space in the name. `select Name, length(Name) from products;`

Comment: I've just ran that script and for the Names, it is one more than the actual length (SMS has length of 4 etc..). Is this what the issue is? And how would I resolve it? As I've done 'LOAD DATA INFILE' and the CSV looks completely fine to me

Comment: Run `update products set Name = trim(Name);` then you'll be set.

Comment: I've just ran this but it says 0 rows affected, so the length is still the same

Comment: Hmmm, ok so try: `update products set Name = left(Name, length(Name) - 1);`

Comment: If you are using notepad, your lines may not be terminated by '\n' but maybe by '\r\n'. Try it

Answer (score 1):

Could you share your csv file content?

It's happened to me too before, and the problem is because there's some blank space in the data in csv file.

So maybe you could parse first your csv file data (remove the "not needed" blank space) before import it to database

Comment: I've just added a picture into the main question. This is only one of the files I need to import, there is a much larger file but again, there is nothing wrong that I can see

Comment: could you block all content in your notepad++ (press: Ctrl + A), screenshot it and post the image again? because I the "invisible" blank line can't be seen if you don't block the content.

Answer (score 1):

This is often caused by spaces or look-alike characters.  If caused by spaces or invisible characters at the beginning/end, you can try:

```
where name like '%SMS%'
```

You can then make this more general:

```
where name like '%S%M%S%'
```

When you get a match, you'll need to do more investigate to find the actual cause.